# Performance aspect of Server.Transfer() with Response.Redirect()

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

`Server.Transfer()` & `Response.Redirect()`, so far good with many tutorials / details on this topic. However, recently I noticed in  the `Apress book: Pro Asp.net 4 in C# 2010` , its mentioned that  `Server.Transfer()` is actually faster.

The many tutorials / discussion on this topic are good but most of them didn't seems to throw light on which one is faster.

So, in this regard::

So far I only know is that there are no round trips involved in `server.Transfer()`. *But what are the various stages in this round trip process in both these methods that created difference in performance*??
Also, *what are other considerations or features that makes Server.Transfer() faster* ??

If there aren't any other feature other than roundtrip explanation, does it will really make much of a difference in terms of speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what are the various stages in this round trip process in both
>   these methods that created difference in performance??

- upon Server.Transfer

  1. the target page starts executing
- upon Response.Redirect

  1. a (usually) HTTP 302 is issued to the client, (network latency)
  2. the client receives the response and issues a request to the server (network latency)
  3. the server processes the request, going through its possible modules (authentication, authorization, url-rewriting, etc...)
  4. asp.net handles some of its events (begin_request, some authorization processing)
  5. you are rendered to step 1 of Server.Transfer, the target page starts executing

> Also, what are other considerations or features that makes
>   Server.Transfer() faster ??

Each step above in itself is a feature that makes Server.Transfer faster.

> If there aren't any other feature other than roundtrip explanation,
>   does it will really make much of a difference in terms of speed?

The difference is just huge. Server.Transfer is about in memory processing and milliseconds, Response.Redirect is about network latency and seconds.

But the choice between Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect is not just about performance it depends on your purpose : Changing the url in the client navbar, or keeping the request context (form data, headers, ...) for processing, handling a possible refresh from the client

Comment: Got the idea. The last 5th line where you used Network latency etc is really  interesting.